# I have two cells each with comma delimited values, I want to combine these into one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, csv, links, concatenation

I have two excel cells(A1 and B1) each contains comma delimited values in, I want to combine these values into one cell (C1), so that the first value from cell A1 is "linked" to the first value from cell B1 by a comma and so on for all the values
For example:
Cell A1 contains the following:  B21:01,B22:02,B23:01,B25:01
Cell B1 contains the following:  1578,2758,10599,5478
Cell C1 should look like this:   B21:01,1578,B22:02,2758,B23:01,10599,B25:01,5478

I have tried =concatenate(transpose(A1:A4)&",") which works well for 1 column, (if I transpose the values into a column) but cannot get it to work across multiple columns.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

### Use this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",0,TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(A1&";"&B1,",",";")))
```

##### This is how it works:

Assuming A1 contains `A,B,C,D,E` and B1 contains `10,20,30,40,50`:

1. `A1 & ";" & B1` concatenates them, adding `;` between them: `A,B,C,D,E;10,20,30,40,50`
2. [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7)((that),`","`,`";"`) expands them into a table:

   | A | B | C | D | E |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 |
3. [TRANSPOSE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027)((that)) transposes that table:

   | A | 10 |
   | --- | --- |
   | B | 20 |
   | C | 30 |
   | D | 40 |
   | E | 50 |
4. [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)(`","`,`0`,(that)) goes row-by-row, cell-by-cell over that table and joins up the contents of the cells, inserting `,` between them: `A,10,B,20,C,30,D,40,E,50`

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to use VBA? If so, this function will do what you want:

```vb
Function pair(ByVal c1 As Range, ByVal c2 As Range, ByVal separator As String) As String
    Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
    arr1 = Split(c1.Value, separator)
    arr2 = Split(c2.Value, separator)
    
    For i = 0 To WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(arr1), UBound(arr2))
        pair = pair & arr1(i) & separator & arr2(i) & separator
    Next i
    pair = Left(pair, Len(pair) - Len(separator))
End Function
```

You can use it in your workbook like so (just replace the semicolons with commas. My language settings use semicolons) :

[image]

**edit:** This function will take the smaller number of elements between the two cells. So if there are 4 values in cell 1 and 3 values in cell 2, it will only make 3 pairs and ignore the 4th value in cell 1. Depending on whether or not this is desirable for you, you might need to modify the function.

**edit2:** and here is a version which strips decimals from the values in second cell:

```vb
Function pair(ByVal c1 As range, ByVal c2 As range, ByVal separator As String) As String
    Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
    arr1 = Split(c1.Value, separator)
    arr2 = Split(c2.Value, separator)
    
    For i = 0 To WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(arr1), UBound(arr2))
        pair = pair & arr1(i) & separator & Split(arr2(i), ".")(0) & separator
    Next i
    pair = Left(pair, Len(pair) - Len(separator))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to remove decimals from a csv string. The second set of numbers have decimals eg B21:01,1578.01,B22:02,2758.54 which I want to remove. The numbers come across into excel as a CSV string and I would like to either remove them prior to running the pair function or after which ever is easier, if it is possible at all.

Comment: @James I added another version of the function to the answer. This version will cut the decimals off. Let me know if it works, thanks!